# FTP Implementation with User Accounts (User Creation) in Wince

Tags: c++, ftp, windows-ce

OS: WinCE 6.0 R3
Platform Builder: PB6

I am trying to create user for FTP in wince. I am using `NTLMSetUserInfo()` for creating user.

It creates USER entry in registry. But when trying to login using that user and password it is not allowing to login.. BAD USER and PASSWORD.

My Registry Settings are:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Ident]
"OrigName"="Kunu"
"Name"="My Device"
"Desc"=LOC_DEFAULTDEVICEDESC


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\FTPD]
"IsEnabled"=dword:1
"UseAuthentication"=dword:1
"UserList"="krunal"
"AllowAnonymous"=dword:0
"AllowAnonymousUpload"=dword:0
"AllowAnonymousVroots"=dword:0
"DefaultDir"="\\Windows"
; Idle time (in seconds) after which the connection is automatically closed. 
Default = 5 mins
"IdleTimeout"=dword:12c
;To control logging
"DebugOutputChannels"=dword:2
"DebugOutputMask"=dword:17
"BaseDir"="\\"
"LogSize"=dword:1000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\Smbserver]
"AdapterList"="*"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\Smbserver\Shares\Root]
"Path"="\\temp"
"Type"=dword:0
"UserList"="admin"



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SMBServer\Shares\VirtualRoot]
    "Type"=dword:0
    "Path"="\\Windows"
    "UserList"="krunal"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\Service\SMBServer]
     "AdapterList"="*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\Redir]
"DefaultDomain"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SMBServer\Shares]
     "UseAuthentication"=dword:1
```

Registry Entry after `NTLMSetUserInfo()`

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\Security\UserAccounts\Mike
```

Under that i am giving Home and Permissions Registry values for access.

still its not working..

I even use API `AuthHelpInitialize()` and `AuthHelpValidateUserW()` to verify the user.

It Returns user not present its failing..

How i can create user and give specific directory access to them...???

Thanks in Advance,
Krunal Soni.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `NLMSetUserInfo()`? Did you try to call `UpdateDCOMSettings()` after the other function?

Comment: Return value of NTLMSetUserInfo() is TRUE. its success..

Comment: i tried calling UpdateDCOMSettings(). but still its giving BAD user and Password

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that you still have to have the users in the UserList value in the FTPD registry key.  Try appending the user name there after calling NTLMSetUserInfo.  You may (not sure) have to stop and re-start the service as well.

Comment: I tried putting user in UserList and i refreshed the SMB0: and FTP0: , services refresh SMB0: services refresh FTP0: but still its not working. Bad user and password. Can u just tell me all the registry setting are fine or not? Anonymous login is working if allowed.